# How can I ensure that my images look clear on my website

Tags: html, image, width

I'm currently working on my portfolio and I'm at the stage of adding images from my computer. However, when I upload an image it only looks clear if I **don't** change the width/height in my html. Whereas when I do change the width/height it becomes stretched and unclear.

This is an example of the image that has had its width/height changed - [image]

Here is the image when I dont change the width/height - [image]

The current image i'm using is a jpeg and the dimensions are 1920 × 1044

I'm resizing the image using this method -

```
   <img class="fade" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/1/" alt="Sports Image"style="width:250px;height:300px;" />
```

Take a look at my codepen to see more. I'm using placeholder images here for the time being. ***Ideally I would like my own photos to be as clear as the photos on my codepen.*** -http://codepen.io/jordan_miguel/pen/gLwJRb?editors=1100

Comment: If you don't want it to stretch, apply a width and height that maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Your resizing is not proportionate.  If you do something like `style="width:50%;"`, the the image will display proportionally but at the specified size percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize it and also keep the aspect ratio of the original image to avoid stretching it.

For example:

```
<img class="fade aspect" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/1/" alt="Sports Image" />
```

CSS:

```
.aspect{
    height: 300px; //However tall you want it to be
    width: auto; //Don't specify the pixels
}
```

This will also work:

```
 .aspect{
    height: 300px; //However tall you want it to be
    width: 100%; //Don't specify the pixels
}
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to be resizing the image.

Answer (score 0):

`<img class="fade" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/1/" alt="Sports Image"style="width:250px;" />`

auto correct height to the width

```
`<img class="fade" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/1/" alt="Sports Image"style="height:300px;" />`
```

auto correct width to the height